# push notification script error

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I have gone through 'http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2' for Push Notification.
Everything is working for me except **when i run php push.php** i got the log as 
 'Push script started (development mode)
1 Exiting with fatal error: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'pushchat'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in /Users/iphonedev/Desktop/Push Test/PushChatServer/push/push.php:83
Stack trace:

## 0 /Users/iphonedev/Desktop/Push Test/PushChatServer/push/push.php(83): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'pushchat', 'd]682#%yI1nb3', Array)

## 1 /Users/iphonedev/Desktop/Push Test/PushChatServer/push/push.php(36): APNS_Push->__construct(Array)

## 2 {main}

'

Please -2 help me, i have spent so much time but unable to find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Thats issue of user privileges with database. Add user by browsing PHPMyAdmin and see below screenshot for assistance.

Add `pushchat` as username and  `d]682#%yI1nb3` as password, select localhost in host field, check all privileges and press go. And you will be rocking.

[image]

Comment: Editing the privileges is not working...i will try 2 delete the user and create it again.

Comment: hi Janak,I have tried to run the script After checking global privileges. but i am getting the same message .

Comment: User:Puhchat                                                     Host: localhost                                               Type: global & database-specific                            Privileges :ALL PRIVILEGE                                                           Grant:YES

Comment: It should work because I too face this error sometimes when I forgot to add user with privileges, wondering in your specific case !

Answer (score 0):

i got it fix by updating the file push_config.php where i replace 'host'     => 'localhost', by 'host'     => 'localhost:8889'.